# Google send an email to me explaining they delete cloud shell

Tags: firebase

Google send an email to me explaining they delete ->

> Deletion notice for your Google Cloud Shell home directory
>
> It's been over 120 days since you opened Cloud Shell from the Google Cloud Platform console. In 7 days, your Cloud Shell home directory will be automatically scheduled for deletion.

I have several Firebase projects, they have huge and important data that is stored in Firebase Storage and Firebase Firestore. Does it mean they will delete firebase databases also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No data will be removed from Cloud Storage or Cloud Firestore when you Cloud Shell home directory is deleted.**

As the email says:

> your Cloud Shell home directory will be automatically scheduled for deletion.

So only data in that home directory will be deleted.